# Azure devops yaml, filter parameter with string

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Short question: how do I do the "enable" part in the pipeline below?

Long question: I have 3 jobs that I need to generate dynamically based on the parameters "params" due to business requirements. The job generated only works if the Job1, Job2 or Job3 is selected as true. Can I access parameters using string like dynamic in c#? ie: parameters["Job1"] or parameters["Job2"] or parameters["Job3"] ?

```
trigger: none

#Package Parameter  
parameters:
- name: Job1
  displayName: 'Job1'
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: Job2
  displayName: 'Job2'
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: Job3
  displayName: 'All Teams'
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: 'params'
  type: object
  default: ["Job1",
            "Job2",
            "Job3"]

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Build_dev
  dependsOn:
  jobs:
  - ${{ each testJob in parameters.params }}:
    - job:
      enable: **If(parameters[testJob] == true) then enable this job**
      displayName: Build ${{ testJob }}
      steps: 
      - script: Build ${{ testJob }}
```

Comment: As of now, this might not be possible. Alternative would be to create a `template` for your job and add three conditions for your parameters that would only call the template in case the if condition evaluates to `true`

Comment: hi sibtain , do you perhaps have a sample code for that? Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi jay, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can disable the jobs that are not set as `true` in the parameters. You can also use [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) for your jobs to skip them

**azure-pipeline.yml**

```
trigger: none

#Package Parameter  
parameters:
- name: Job1
  displayName: 'Job1'
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: Job2
  displayName: 'Job2'
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: Job3
  displayName: 'All Teams'
  type: boolean
  default: false

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Build_dev
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
    - ${{ if eq(parameter.Value, 'true') }}:
      - template: job-template.yml
        parameters:
          jobName: ${{ parameter.Key }}
```

**job-template.yml**

```
parameters:
  jobName: ''

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
  displayName: Build ${{ parameters.jobName }}
  steps: 
  - script: echo "Build ${{ parameters.jobName }}"
```